# Chat schema Design for deleting messages

Tags: mongodb, schema, chat, system, whatsapp

I am making a chat service for a dating app , for which i need to design schema. My Stack is MEAN. using socket.js for realtime commuication. i have to design my chat app like whatsapp. like i need whatsapp temporary ( one side delete ) and permanent delete ( deleted by both side, then it will be erased from memory too).Problem is how should i implement this?
[image]

As my app always be one on one chats. i was thinking like use key "action" for deletion feature,empty by default.

if one user (suppose user1) delete a msg from its side then i will marked this as "DELETED/user1".then at time of fetching msgs. i will not be sending this msg to this user.
and if that msg is deleted by other user too or deleted as "DELETE FOR ALL" like whatsapp by uuser1, then i will be marking field as "DELETED/ALL".

My other thought is as maintaning 2 sources of truth.
like maintaining two record of same connversation for each user.

if user1 delete,then it will delete msg from user1's conversation.

if user2 delete,then it will delete msg from user2's conversation.

if user1 delete as "DELETE FOR ALL",then it will delete msg from both conversation.
problem with this approach is that , in future i have to perform every operaions twice like liking msg,editing msg etc.

what your suggestion on this problem?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your chat is **1 on 1** not group chat, **Multiple field** in this scenario would be recommended.

If user1 is `from` and he delete message the data would be like

```
fromDelete: true
toDelete: false
```

If user2 is `to` and he delete message the data would be like

```
fromDelete: false
toDelete: true
```

If user1 is `to` and he delete **all** message the data would be like

```
fromDelete: true
toDelete: true
```

By doing so, you can **modify** or **query** data more easily.

You can also use this method in the future if you want to add `edit` or `like`